# Order By Sum of Two Fields

Tags: sql, cakephp, mysql

Let's say I have a table with karma_up and karma_down.  Everytime someone votes up karma_up gets incremented and everytime someone votes down karma_down gets incremented one as well.  How can I pull these a selection of rows and have them ordered by the sum of these new values?  ORDER BY (karma_up - karma_down) does not seem to work how I want.  I simply want the rows with the highest karma up top.

Comment: The final outcome of this question was

SELECT * , CAST( karma_up - karma_down AS SIGNED ) AS karma_total
FROM  `links` 
ORDER BY karma_total DESC 

I needed to CAST because I was getting very large numbers for my negative karma values.  This is what I get for unsigning my karma_up and karma_down fields but CAST() was the solution.  Thanks ya'll!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Very simple

```
SELECT 
ID, KARMA_UP, KARMA_DOWN, (KARMA_UP-KARMA_DOWN) AS USER_KARMA 
FROM KARMA 
ORDER BY USER_KARMA DESC
```

Comment: The OP wants the highest on top and I think he needs DESC as Bill Karwin posted.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT *, karma_up - karma_down AS karma_total 
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY karma_total DESC;
```

Comment: Ouch, posted a correct answer just after the selected answer was posted.

Comment: You win some, you lose some.  What's important is that the OP got his question answered.

Comment: True, but just being sympathetic.

Comment: OP = Original Poster.  The person who asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work? If not, could you include the results in your question? Ordering on an expression ought to work as expected.

```
SELECT `post_id`, `karma_up`, `karma_down`, `karma_up` - `karma_down` AS `total`
ORDER BY `total` DESC
```