# MySQL ORDER BY with two columns summed

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a page where rows are displayed. Each row has two columns that are the point of my question, rating and usage. When the page is first loaded, there is no presorting and the page displays just fine. Code for when it is working:

```
if (!$sortby) {

    $getdata = mysql_query("select * FROM traditional") or die(mysql_error());

    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($getdata)){

        $category = $data["category"];
        $overview = $data["overview"];
        $ratingcount = $data["ratingcount"];
        $ratingscore = $data["ratingscore"];
        $usage = $data["usage"];
        $location = $data["location"];
        $calculaterating = $ratingscore / $ratingcount;
        if (!$calculaterating) {
            $rating = "None";
        } else {
            $rating = $calculaterating;
        }

        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr colspan='4'>";
        echo "<td class='selectcategory' width='40%'>";
        echo "<a href='$location'>$category</a>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td class='categorymenu' style='vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;   
        padding: 5px;' width='40%'>";
        echo $overview;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td class='categorymenu' width='10%'>";
        echo $rating;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td class='categorymenu' width='10%'>";
        echo $usage;
        echo "</td>";
    }
```

Here's where things stop working. There is a drop down menu on the page that allows the user to sort by usage or rating. When they choose one the page refreshes and $sortby is populated by either rating or usage. Here's the rest of the code, when things stop working:

```
} else {

    if ($sortby = "rating") {
        $sort = "rating";
    } else {
        $sort = "`usage`";
    }
    $getdata = mysql_query("select category,overview,SUM(ratingscore / ratingcount) as   
'rating',`usage`,location FROM traditional ORDER BY $sort DESC") or die(mysql_error());

    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($getdata)){

        $category = $data["category"];
        $overview = $data["overview"];
        $rating = $data["rating"];
        $usage = $data["usage"];
        $location = $data["location"];

        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr colspan='4'>";
        echo "<td class='selectcategory' width='40%'>";
        echo "<a href='$location'>$category</a>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td class='categorymenu' style='vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;   
        padding: 5px;' width='40%'>";
        echo $overview;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td class='categorymenu' width='10%'>";
        echo $rating;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td class='categorymenu' width='10%'>";
        echo $usage;
        echo "</td>";
    }
}
```

When $sortby is not populated, about 10 rows display. With the code that isn't working (when one attempts to sort the results), only one row displays (don't know why?) and the one rating row that shows up isn't calculated right anyway. I have read a bunch of other posts that sort of deal with this (which kind of helped me craft the bad code as I currently have it). But I guess I'm just not understanding from what I'm getting from others' posts.

Comment: `'rating'` in the second select is incorrect. aliases should not be strings (which is what the `'` turns the word `rating` into. if that's a derived field and does not exist as a field in your table, then sorting by `rating` will fail with a "no such column" error.

Comment: Nope. That was me misinterpreting another post's code. I thought that doing that kind of created a temporary "column" named rating. At least I guessed that's what that was doing. I just the two columns (as you'll notice on the first time around that works) are stored as the number of ratings and the total score of thsoe ratings, which gives me the average on the output. I just can't figure out how to sort by that average output.

Comment: Any advice as to how I can order by the average rating as it is calculated in the code section that works?

Comment: you can sort by derived values, that's not the problem. I'd suggest echoing out the generated query before you run it, and run it yourself manually, and see what the results are. check the syntax of both versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309203/order-by-sum-of-two-fields

Comment: You're dead right there Alex. I looked at quite a few posts similar to that, but that was way clearer than anything else I read. Just a few tweaks (got rid of the sum, added the fields ratingcount and ratingscore to the select field before I derived the rating field) and the code works just fine. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUM` is an aggregate operator and using it without `GROUP BY` will make your whole result set collapse into one row where `result` is set to the sum of the results of all rows.

I'm not sure why you're using `SUM` at all, if you want to have the same rows as in the first query with just ordering added, it should be something like;

```
SELECT category, overview, ratingscore / ratingcount AS rating,
    `usage`, location FROM traditional ORDER BY $sort DESC
```

If I'm misunderstanding your desired result set, let me know, but `SUM` without a `GROUP BY` is definitely not what you want in your case.

Comment: This was the problem. Figured it out just before you posted this. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can go for if else for query... so that you can use simple ORDER BY query.. and echo query generated output.